# Use Common Table Expression (CTE) to reduce locks (max_locks_per_transaction)

Tags: postgresql, locking, cte, temporary-tables

I am getting

```
"ERROR: out of shared memory"
```

presumably because my plpgsql function drops/creates a lot of temporary tables.

Searching for a solution to the issue, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961809/683218) that says:

> So I guess one answer is that you will need enough locks to cope with
>   all these tables being added/dropped throughout the transaction.
>   Alternatively, you could try to reuse the temp tables between queries,
>   simply truncate them to remove all the temp data

In order to avoid having too many looks, I am thinking about rewriting as many temporary table code using Common Table Expressions (CTEs).

My questions are:

Do the table expressions in CTEs use locks that count towards `max_locks_per_transaction`?

Will replacing temp tables with CTEs solve the `max_locks_per_transaction` problem?

Related:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490664/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132533

Answer (score 1):

A CTE is no table and won't need an entry in the lock table.

It is probably a good idea not to create and drop temporary tables all the time. Apart from the problem you are experiencing, it can lead to a bloated `pg_attribute` catalog table (all those added and deleted columns).

Mind that a CTE is only for the duration of a single table.